# How to iterate through whole array backwards starting from random index?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array like this (it doesn't need to be sorted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

So, given an specific index I want to iterate through whole array backwards.

Example:

```
index = 1
output: 7,6,5,4,3,2,1

index = 3
output: 2,1,7,6,5,4,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `i = (i - 1 + array.length) % array.length` expression to wrap around the end.

When `i` is above zero, the subtraction of `1` works the usual way; adding `array.length` and taking a remainder have no effect.

When `i` is zero, the result of the expression becomes `array.length - 1`, which puts you at the last index of the array.